# F# application structure logging / repositories etc

Tags: logging, architecture, f#, functional-dependencies

I'm gradually switching into F# for a lot of my home projects but I'm a little stumped as to how to wire together complete applications, and more particularly cross-cutting concerns.

In C# if I want to log stuff I'd use dependency injection to pass an ILogger into each class, and then this can be called nice and easily from the code. I can verify in my tests that given a particular situation logs are written, by passing in a mock and verifying it.

```
public class MyClass
{
    readonly ILogger _logger;
    public MyClass(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public int Divide(int x, int y)
    {
        if(y == 0)
        {
            _logger.Warn("y was 0");
            return 0;
        }
        return x / y;
    }
}
```

In F# I'm using modules a lot more, so the above would become

```
module Stuff

let divde x y =
    match y with 
    | 0 -> 0
    | _ -> x / y
```

Now if I had a module called Logging I could just open that and use a log function from there in the case of y being 0, but how would I inject this for unit testing?

I could have each function take a log function (string -> unit) and then use partial application to wire them up but that seems like an awful lot of work, as would creating a new function that wraps the actual call inside a logging call. Is there a particular pattern or a bit of F# that I'm missing that can do it?
(I've seen the kprintf function but I still don't know how you'd specify the function for various test scenarios, whilst using a concrete implementation for the complete application)

Similarly how would you stub out a repository that fetched data? Do you need to have some class instantiated and set the CRUD functions on it, or is there a way to inject which modules you open (aside from #define)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003487/architectural-thinking-in-functional-languages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192090/how-do-you-design-a-functional-program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic answer. Firstly, it seems you're thinking of classes and modules as being interchangeable. Classes encapsulate data, and in that sense are more analogous to records and DUs. Modules, on the other hand, encapsulate functionality (they're compiled to static classes). So, I think you already mentioned your options: partial function application, passing the functions around as data, or... dependency injection. For your particular case it seems easiest to keep what you have.

An alternative is using preprocessor directives to include different modules.

```
#if TESTING 
open LogA
#else
open LogB
#endif
```

DI isn't necessarily a poor fit in a functional language. It's worth pointing out, F# makes defining and fulfilling interfaces even easier than, say, C#.

Comment: hmmm, so imagine that F# didn't have classes just records and DUs, then the logging would have to go in modules as you typically want to log about an operation (at least in debug) rather than the result of an operation. This would mean that DI is out the window so partial application is all that's left. Can you recommend any reading about functional architecture by any chance? As it's been around so long I'm sure these sorts of things have been solved already but all the books I've seen concentrate on the "small" rather than the "large"

Comment: I wish I did. I remember struggling with this early on too. I expected "large" architecture to be radically different in F#. Some functional languages allow modules to be parameterized. Unfortunately, F# doesn't. OO is still a good approach "in the large". I know the question has been posed a few times on SO. A quick search turned up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003487/architectural-thinking-in-functional-languages. There may be others.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I did a search earlier but couldn't find anything that actually gave any guidance. I think you're right with the partial application though, I suppose it only has to go up one level of encapsulation anyway before dependencies should be starting to get wired up by the hosting application.

Answer (score 3):

If you won't need to change the logger at runtime, then using a compiler directive or `#if` to choose between two implementations of a logger (as suggested by Daniel) is probably the best and the simplest way to go.

From the functional point of view, dependency injection means the same thing as parameterizing all your code by a logging function. The bad thing is that you need to propagate the function everywhere (and that makes the code a bit messy). You can also just make a global mutable variable in a module and set it to an instance of some `ILogger` interface - I think this is actually quite acceptable solution for F#, because you need to change this variable only in a couple of places.

Another (more "pure") alternative would be to define a *workflow* (aka monad) for logging. This is a good choice only if you write all your code in F#. This example is discussed in Chapter 12 of my book, which is [available as a free sample](http://manning.com/petricek/SampleChapter12.pdf). Then you can write something like this:

```
let write(s) = log {
  do! logMessage("writing: " + s)
  Console.Write(s) }

let read() = log {
  do! logMessage("reading")
  return Console.ReadLine() }

let testIt() = log {
  do! logMessage("starting")
  do! write("Enter name: ")
  let! name = read()
  return "Hello " + name + "!" }
```

The good thing about this approach is that it is a nice functional technique. Testing code should be easy, because a function that returns `Log<'TResult>` essenitally gives you a value as well as a record of its side-effects, so you can just compare the results! However, it may be an overkill, because you'd have to wrap every computation that uses logging in the `log { .. }` block.

Comment: Thanks Tomas,
I'm still on the bent that mutability is evil. In my C# code I always make dependencies readonly. If I make a mutable logger in the code then I guess there is no easy way to protect it from accidental re-assignment. I suppose as I mentioned in another comment though that the upper levels of the application (derived functionality) would not be accessing the lower modules anyway.

Comment: @Dylan - Yes, the declaration of modules is order sensitive, so your logging module would have to go first. It is true that mutability is evil (in F#) in general. However, if you don't need to re-assing the logger, then it is just the simplest option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of your C# code in F# which is similar to the initial C#

```
module stuff

type MyClass(logger:#Ilogger) =
    member x.Divide a b =
        if b=0 then 
            logger.Warn("y was 0")
            0
        else
            x/y
```

this should allow you to use the same techniques that you know from C# for your logging

Comment: thanks, but I'd rather use C# for this type of approach. I didn't really make it clear but it was more for how you'd do this approach using just records and function definitions without classes

Comment: A minor not - you don't need the `#ILogger` type in this case, because F# inserts the cast automatically when calling a method or a constructor. Using hash-type here seems a bit weird - I suppose it even makes the whole class generic (parameterized over logger type), which is not needed here.

Comment: @Tomas - thats what happens when I don't bother to use the compiler to check my code